# interaction problem with boost.signals2?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-signals2

I'm trying to call a signal after an booost::asio::async_read from inside
a function called by boost::asio::io_service. The run function runs
in a thread, and the observers are connected in a different thread.

This is causing errors. It's my program or it's not possible to invoke a handler
that is running in another thread from io_service::run? In other words,
is it possible inter-thread communication of handler invocation invoking
the signal from another thread? Thanks in advance.